# Prevent BackButton press while showing ad

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, cordova-admob

Basically I want to disable backbutton press event while showing `admob` video

I have written below code in phonegap app

`document.addEventListener('backbutton', onBackKeyDown, false);`

```
function onBackKeyDown(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

This code is working for app pages, But not working when displaying `admob` ad's. Is it possible to prevent default behaviour of back button press while showing `ads`?

Comment: While you're at it, maybe you should ask how to pop up ads while your app isn't running, and maybe how to hide a cryptominer. Heck, why not ask how to implement ransomware on Android. Point is - this is not an appropriate question to ask, and you should consider creating _good_ apps to increase revenue, not spam.

Comment: Understood, @JasonShuler. This was actually a very old issue, and I'm not entirely sure what the actual problem was at the time. Somehow, AdMob managed to resolve it. Nevertheless, thanks for your comment now.

Answer (score 1):

You can override Activity's `onBackPressed()` and check to see if video is playing, if yes stay and else provide default implementation like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(!videoIsPlaying) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the android code, I want solution in phonegap JS code

Answer (score 1):

I think this violates "Interfering with Apps, Third-party Ads, or Device Functionality" policy:

"Ads should not appear after the user has exited the app, or **after the user has pressed the back button** to exit the app."

Your app could be removed from the store due to this violation.

Comment: This. OP is trying to accomplish something evil.

Answer (score 0):

> *The event fires when the user presses the back button. To override the default back-button behavior, register an event listener for the `backbutton` event. It is no longer necessary to call any other method to override the back-button behavior.*

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

function onBackKeyDown() {
    // Handle the back button
}
```

[Source](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/cordova/events/events.html#backbutton)

To have a special behavior while showing the admob ad it shouldn't be any different, as the author of the admob plugin stated on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30638074/363262).

Comment: But its not working having different behavior while displaying ad. Did it will be device OS specific? Currently checking on Moto mobile. Strange behavior didnt get any clue whats happening wrong.